# javac is still not recognized, I tried everything

Tags: java

I am new to programming.

I want to set java environment, but it is not working even I set the path.

This is the directory, I put the first one on path `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin`:
[image]

here is my path for java in system variable:
[image]

I tried to restart cmd and even my laptop, but it is still not working

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Have you set a `JAVA_HOME` system variable?

Comment: Please paste text, your images are difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java compiler (`javac`) is generally not included within the `jre`; you will instead need to install the `jdk` or the Java Development Kit. You seem to be doing everything else correctly though. Good luck!